# Unable to read table from website using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to read a website's content using below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url  = "https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377" 
r    = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

print(soup)
```

In the result, I am unable to see the the table which I could see when I do "Inspect" element manually in the browser.

[image]

Using selenium could be one solution. But I am looking for some other alternate solutions, if possible.

Any idea on how to read the data from underlying script in HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that case you should try out newly released [requests_html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) library which has the capability to handle dynamically generated items. This is how your script should look like if you comply with what I have just said:

```
import requests_html

session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
items = r.html.find("table#DataTables_Table_0",first=True)
for item in items.find("tr"):
    data = [td.text for td in item.find("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Sr.', 'Stock Name', 'Symbol', 'Links', '% Chg', 'Price', 'Volume']
['1', 'Axis Bank Limited', 'AXISBANK', 'P&F | F.A', '-1.33%', '522.6', '12,146,623']
['2', 'Reliance Industries Limited', 'RELIANCE', 'P&F | F.A', '-1.29%', '900.05', '14,087,564']
['3', 'Tata Steel Limited', 'TATASTEEL', 'P&F | F.A', '-1.89%', '600.2', '11,739,582']
```

Comment: Awesome. Really appreciate your help and thanks a lot!

Comment: how can i do this in c# ?

Comment: It ain't working. I got following error : 
RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.

Comment: I tested it just now and found It working perfectly. However, if you face any issue or have any question, try creating a post describing your requirements and code attempt. Thanks..

Comment: @SIM sure. I've created one here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64319691/scraping-js-enabled-sites-for-automation