# Scraping JS enabled sites for automation

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape one particular site (https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377)
I am trying to access the provided table in the URL. This table can be of dynamic form. The site is JS enabled hence it was redundant of me to try HTML scraping.
Next, I tried to access XHR elements using cURL, it did work. I used given below code:

```
import requests
headers = {
'authority': 'chartink.com',
'pragma': 'no-cache',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
'x-csrf-token': 'HYMZ6XnOySvn1w4fHEN0Hu1ublftvidgdBD5qywR',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36',
'sentry-trace': 'd9b8f7ffcae445f7a74913d5ac143918-9fa7556ebb76186c-0',
'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
'origin': 'https://chartink.com',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'referer': 'https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377',
'accept-language': 'en-IN,en;q=0.9,hi-IN;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.5',
'cookie': '_ga=GA1.2.468738165.1600680012; remember_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d=eyJpdiI6Inp6YWdERUJHSGxoWmhRaE00MGhONHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiSXN1d09PXC9USmpGb2lFR21naFd1Q3RlcCtKSDdUXC8zdGRnMkRoQmNcL2loXC9tT0tMXC9sc0JtallJVCtNczVhVjhIdGUyb0xqMTIydlc0RWtQYVZcLzF1aFd3aXRPM0M3MDVObUtNK1FtdmJtZjY1YUxNbTlyTHhNWFhjU3VZNXpUTWY0SjZ4M1o1VEcydk1DWDY5YWVSdWRjbVwvQmkyYmlDT2VMWFVCM043Y2JIY21UTjNsdnJLaE1qSnNybmM2WVhISyIsIm1hYyI6IjhlNjBiZWUxMWU3NTBkOTRjM2NlYTZiNGI3YzJhYjg4M2E0OWI2MDU3ZDZkYWUzNzE1YjYxOTRhMTllMjY2ZWQifQ%3D%3D; __utmc=102564947; PHPSESSID=e3797d9e58f9f56b0307e7840f6839f7; bfp_sn_rf_8b2087b102c9e3e5ffed1c1478ed8b78=Direct/External; bfp_sn_rt_8b2087b102c9e3e5ffed1c1478ed8b78=1601299430046; bafp=d8afd2b0-018d-11eb-b966-a1985446bf25; hbcm_sd=1%7C1602315380999; _gid=GA1.2.729526333.1602491131; __utma=102564947.468738165.1600680012.1601134509.1602499714.2; __utmz=102564947.1602499714.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InVXSEFpN2xiYWZqWDkzNEdWZVBTSkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQlM2eVBYMjdYR3N4QTh6YmtFWmNoTUtOVHBIOFVoUG04WTdcL05iUm4yZExQR3ZucHlPVHhucVwvbjlHTW9VcmZCIiwibWFjIjoiMWEyMzViZDQ5YWI1YzIzY2UzYTdkNzRlN2UyZmYzNmY1ZWNkYTBmZmJmOWI2YjZmOGRmN2U2Y2IzOGE5ZmQwNiJ9; ci_session=eyJpdiI6ImtcLzNBOGxOb1l2bFlyOEFnQ2dxVHNBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjRpNVhXOWtGZlV0TWdwZlhIVGRmWFgrcGFyblwveGlkdVU5aHJraVdvbFROOURUa2Zhc2pcLzJNOE9qa0FwcjlwbSIsIm1hYyI6IjVlYTUwNDgxN2U0NTU4OWE0NTgxOTMwNjNjMzdhM2Q5MjRiMjJjMTBkYzI0ZTdkOTg1YTg5YmIxNTM3NzFlMDQifQ%3D%3D',}
data = {'scan_clause': '( {33489} ( latest close > 10 ) ) '}
response = requests.post('https://chartink.com/screener/process', headers=headers, data=data)
data = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.json_normalize(data['data'])
```

It worked. However certain elements of it will get expire after a certain time. CSRF token, sentry- trace and cookies.

After a certain time, the code will start having errors while running it due to tokens mismatch.

I then used the given below method (following another thread) but it also doesn't work.

```
import requests_html
session = requests_html.HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
items = r.html.find("table#DataTables_Table_0",first=True)
for item in items.find("tr"):
data = [td.text for td in item.find("th,td")]
print(data)
```

But again I received error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead.
```

When I used AsyncHTMLSession then there were some other errors. All in all, it's been a dead-end for me.

One can add an explanation in either approach.

Comment: Is this version deployed any where on web ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get all 137 results in one go. Try using the base url to collect csrf token and then send http post requests along with appropriate parameters to get json response in order to fetch required content out of it. Here is how you can:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377"
url = 'https://chartink.com/screener/process'

payload = {
    'scan_clause': '( {33489} ( latest close > 10 ) )'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    csrf = soup.select_one("[name='csrf-token']")['content']
    s.headers['x-csrf-token'] = csrf
    r = s.post(url,data=payload)
    for item in r.json()['data']:
        print(item['name'],item['nsecode'],item['per_chg'],item['close'],item['volume'])
```

Results are like:

```
Mrf Limited MRF -0.34 58587.1 9057
BANKNIFTY BANKNIFTY -0.56 23712.8 0
Shree Cements Limited SHREECEM -1.14 20956.1 56254
Page Industries Limited PAGEIND -0.29 20898.75 26311
Nestle India Limited NESTLEIND -0.82 15902.2 58171
Bosch Limited BOSCHLTD -1.64 12529.1 37951
```

Comment: how to send a multiple playload and get result. i am getting Empty df when sending a List of Playload option via loop

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because Jupyter Notebook / Spyder IDE already have their own event loop. To scrape the table use `AsyncHTMLSession` in Jupyter Notebook / Spyder. Or use your above code in a regular IDE, and it will work.

```
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
r = await asession.get('https://chartink.com/screener/test-121377')
await r.html.arender()

items = r.html.find("table#DataTables_Table_0",first=True)
for item in items.find("tr"):
    data = [td.text for td in item.find("th,td")]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['Sr.', 'Stock Name', 'Symbol', 'Links', '% Chg', 'Price', 'Volume']
['1', 'Coforge (Niit Tech)', 'COFORGE', 'P&F | F.A', '8.16%', '2667.6', '1,741,341']
['2', 'Mindtree Limited', 'MINDTREE', 'P&F | F.A', '3.86%', '1562.35', '1,973,673']
['3', 'Shriram Transport Finance Company Limited', 'SRTRANSFIN', 'P&F | F.A', '3.21%', '661.65', '6,179,353']
['4', 'Gmr Infrastructure Limited', 'GMRINFRA', 'P&F | F.A', '2.98%', '24.2', '20,661,331']
['5', 'Escorts Limited', 'ESCORTS', 'P&F | F.A', '2.66%', '1254.2', '2,100,408']
['6', 'Itc Limited', 'ITC', 'P&F | F.A', '2.59%', '172.2', '66,250,654']
['7', 'Srf Limited', 'SRF', 'P&F | F.A', '2.49%', '4372.95', '458,060']
['8', 'Biocon Limited', 'BIOCON', 'P&F | F.A', '2.38%', '462.65', '6,012,803']
['9', 'Infosys Limited', 'INFY', 'P&F | F.A', '2.29%', '1132.1', '14,633,780']
['10', 'Upl Limited', 'UPL', 'P&F | F.A', '1.97%', '507.1', '3,332,484']
['11', 'United Spirits Limited', 'MCDOWELL-N', 'P&F | F.A', '1.84%', '530.95', '2,558,898']
['12', 'Lupin Limited', 'LUPIN', 'P&F | F.A', '1.68%', '1046.5', '2,276,511']
['13', 'Torrent Pharmaceuticals Limited', 'TORNTPHARM', 'P&F | F.A', '1.47%', '2840.8', '405,203']
['14', 'Bharti Infratel Limited', 'INFRATEL', 'P&F | F.A', '1.34%', '189', '8,613,164']
['15', 'Asian Paints Limited', 'ASIANPAINT', 'P&F | F.A', '1.33%', '2077.85', '2,182,836']
['16', "Dr. Reddy's Laboratories Limited", 'DRREDDY', 'P&F | F.A', '1.31%', '5220.5', '1,935,812']
['17', 'Cipla Limited', 'CIPLA', 'P&F | F.A', '1.31%', '813.65', '6,612,623']
['18', 'Hindalco Industries Limited', 'HINDALCO', 'P&F | F.A', '1.26%', '172.15', '16,792,494']
['19', 'Hcl Technologies Limited', 'HCLTECH', 'P&F | F.A', '1.17%', '865.8', '8,717,565']
['20', 'Power Grid Corporation Of India Limited', 'POWERGRID', 'P&F | F.A', '1.14%', '159.8', '11,627,290']
['21', 'Maruti Suzuki India Limited', 'MARUTI', 'P&F | F.A', '1.05%', '7136.65', '799,713']
['22', 'Berger Paints (i) Limited', 'BERGEPAINT', 'P&F | F.A', '1.01%', '608.7', '1,014,098']
['23', 'Interglobe Aviation Limited', 'INDIGO', 'P&F | F.A', '0.96%', '1380.3', '1,294,658']
['24', 'Wipro Limited', 'WIPRO', 'P&F | F.A', '0.94%', '377.5', '52,966,063']
['25', 'Bharat Electronics Limited', 'BEL', 'P&F | F.A', '0.81%', '93.55', '7,136,715']
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. However above method won't publish all the results but only 25( as it is how it is displayed over site). It will  be better to fetch data from AJAX call. That way one can list all the data.